# sqlite3 module for Jython

Tags: java, python, sqlite, jython, javax.script

I'm using Java Scripting API to execute some external Python scripts from my Java application. The python scripts use sqlite3 module. Execution of the application is resulting in error

```
ImportError: No module named sqlite3
```

As I look into the `Lib` directory(which is in the classpath) of Jython, there's no sqlite3 module. Hence, my search begins and I found one `_sqlite3.py` file which is an implementation of `javasqlite` (http://bugs.jython.org/issue1682864). It's use produced more similar kind of errors.

Then I searched the original python's `sqlite3` package(original directory) from the python's standard library location and placed it in the Jython's `Lib` folder. It then could not find imported `_sqlite` module which is the `_sqlite.so` library (actual C implementation).

So, now I need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to use a CPython extension in Jython, so you're out of luck there.

There's a Java wrapper for SQLite here: http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/
This is not going to work quite like a Python database driver, so using it would require some adaptation.

Not fun, but perhaps you (or someone else) could write some Jython around it to produce a drop-in replacement for the `sqlite3` module.

Comment: Yes you are correct. So I threw away Jython and executed the Python scripts using ProcessBuilder classes. Worked like a charm. Thanks anyway.