# django on jython using django-jython

Tags: python, django, sqlite, jython

**I would appreciate it if you read my poor English**

**I use :**

> windows
>
> Jython 2.7rc2
>
> jdk-8u45
>
> django 1.8
>
> django-jython 1.7.0b2

I try `jython startproject mysite`, and succeed

then I try `jython manage.py runserver 8080` and fail

Detail:

In **settings.py** :

```
     in DATABASES :
                     'ENGINE': 'doj.db.backends.sqlite3'
     in INSTALLED_APPS:
                      I add  'doj',
```

The same with https://pythonhosted.org/django-jython/index.html

The results:

> raise
>   ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:'doj.db.backends.sqlite'
>   isn't an a
>                 vailable database backend.
>                   Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
>                  u'base', u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
>            **Error was: cannot import name BaseDatabaseWrapper**

so  I  try  **django.db.backends.sqlite**  instead  of  **doj.db.backends.sqlite**  in  **settings.py**  at  **DATABASES**

and unluckily:

> raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading either pysqlite2
>                  or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): %s" % exc)
>               django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either
>                   pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): **No module** 
>                 **named sqlite3**

and I also try **"doj.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2"**  and failed ,too   **Error was: cannot import name BaseDatabaseWrapper**

I have searched and try  all day  already but still can not solve.

thanks for your help!!!

Comment: try doj.db.backends.sqlite3

Comment: I try it ,and the same error:  thank you

Comment: its no module named sqlite   and  no module named sqlite3   almost the same

Answer (score 0):

Jpython has same problems about sqlite3 here is similar question and answer.

[sqlite3 module for Jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875212/sqlite3-module-for-jython)

Comment: and I also try "doj.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2"  and failed ,too   Error was: cannot import name BaseDatabaseWrapper